# Output of xpath selection different from what i see in my browser

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to fetch image relative link of an image in order to download it.
You can find an example at this address: https://www.laforet.com/agence-immobiliere/colombes/acheter/colombes/appartement-2-pieces-20909147

The part of the html i see in my browser is this one:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="property__fullsize" data-v-6ac7cd72="" data-v-476b61a8="">
    <img src="/media/cache/office9/laforet_paris17villiers/catalog/images/pr_p/2/0/9/0/9/1/4/7/20909147c.jpg?method=max&amp;size=medium&amp;timestamp=1633799295" alt="" class="**property__photo**" data-v-e11dca30="" data-v-476b61a8="" data-v-6ac7cd72="">
    <span class="svg-icon icon-full-size" data-v-10c7d875="" data-v-476b61a8="" data-v-6ac7cd72="">
        <svg data-v-10c7d875="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 23.249 23.248" role="presentation" width="18" height="18" class="white">
            <g data-v-10c7d875="" id="full-size" transform="translate(0 -0.002)">
                <path data-v-10c7d875="" id="Tracé_1008" data-name="Tracé 1008" d="deleted for brevity"</path>
                <path data-v-10c7d875="" id="Tracé_1009" data-name="Tracé 1009" d="deleted for brevity" transform="translate(-122.883 -122.879)"></path>
                <path data-v-10c7d875="" id="Tracé_1010" data-name="Tracé 1010" d="deleted for brevity" transform="translate(-0.004 -122.879)"></path>
                <path data-v-10c7d875="" id="Tracé_1011" data-name="Tracé 1011" d="deleted for brevity" transform="translate(-124.215 0)"></path>
            </g>
        </svg>
    <!---->
    </span>
</a>
```

I want to have this part

**"/media/cache/office9/laforet_paris17villiers/catalog/images/pr_p/2/0/9/0/9/1/4/7/20909147c.jpg?method=max&size=medium&timestamp=1633799295"**

The xpath to reach this part should be quite straightforward:

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="property__photo"]/@src').get()
```

or

```
response.css(".property__photo").getall()
```

There doesn't seem to be any trap, I think I reached the good part of the html.
The problem is that, the output is this

```
'<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%221%22%20height%3D%221%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20%25%7Bw%7D%20%25%7Bh%7D%22%20preserv eAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22100%25%22%20height%3D%22100%25%22%20style%3D%22fill%3Atransparent%3B%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="" width="1" height="1" class="property__photo" data-v-e11dca30 data-v-476b61a8>'
```

Why is there a difference between he html I see in my browser and the html scrapy inported ? is that javascript ? What kind of format is it ? Can i extract an image from this string ? Is this behaviour triggered by the webpage or by scrapy ?

---

### EDIT

---

I decided to find another way to extract the links as adviced by @SuperUser.
I still do not know exactly what function changed the content of the html between what i see in my browser and what scrapy is downloading. Numerous obfuscated javascripts are contained within the page and I cannot find the culprit. Nevertheless, I found a workaround by taking content of  flags.

Comment: It's definitely because of javascript. You can't extract the iamge from the string, search for "url decoder" and see, You'll need to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Get the `::attr(value)`.

Please use

```
response.css('img.property__photo::attr(href)').extract()
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't work as it seems there is no href in the html scrapy imported. And the "href" in the html i see in my browser points to "javascript:void(0)".